# How to get maximum key/values pair array from a associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like below

```
[
    [
        'k1' => 'v1',
        'k2' => 'v2'
    ],
    [
        'k1' => 'v1',
        'k2' => 'v2',
        'k3' => 'v3'
    ],
    [
        'k1' => 'v1',
        'k2' => 'v2',
        'k3' => 'v3',
        'k4' => 'v4'
    ]
]
```

**Is it possible to get 3rd array which has maximum key/value pair.**

**EDIT**

Let me clear a bit.

- array[0] contains 2 key/value pair.
- array[1] contains 3 key/value pair.
- array[2] contains 4 key/value pair.

So I need to get array which contains maximum key/value pair.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to get `max` value of key and `max` value of value ? or you want to get max value of key and its value ? or max value with its key ? please specify.

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: I need to get the array with maximum fields i.e (keys/values).

Comment: @AabirHussain can you please show us your actual array and expected output ?

Comment: hope my edit would clear the question. @Tiger I can't show you the actual Array becuase it is a huge array with more than 50 key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bellow approach for getting your result :

```
$array = array(
                array('K1'=>'v1'),
                array('K1'=>'v1','K2'=>'v2'),
                array('K1'=>'v1','K2'=>'v2','K3'=>'v3')
                );
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));
print_r($maxs);
```

It will provide you output as :

```
Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

Then you can get your key value pairs according to your requirement after passing this maxs array value like this.

```
$myMaxValue = $array[$maxs[0]];
print_r($myMaxValue);
```

This provide you below result :

```
Array ( [K1] => v1 [K2] => v2 [K3] => v3 )
```

Comment: Thanks for max($array).